# Resize and drag issues with jQuery dialog over iFrame

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jQuery dialogs over an iframe in my webpage and the resizing and dragging does not work as expected.

What it does, is it stops working when your mouse gets outside of the window, which is quite annoying because it happens really fast. This happens by both dragging and resizing of the dialogs.

Here is a small skeleton in which I was able to reproduce the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.15.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.15.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {          
        $("#awesomewindow").dialog();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: red; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <div id="awesomewindow">
        Window content here!
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden">
        <iframe src="Blue.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="100%" width="100%" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the iframe just steals the focus, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Thanks for watching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set these two parameters to make it work:

```
$(function () {
        $("#awesomewindow").dialog({
            iframe: true,
            modal : true
        });
    });
```

Comment: iframe is no option of dialog, and with modal, it works, true, but I do not want the dialogs to be modal..

Comment: well that's a really hard one or seems impossible to me. as when you have that iframe when you go out of the box you are on a different document and jquery is tracking the x and y for the document that the div is on. maybe set the overlay opacity to zero? its still modal but not visible.

Comment: I think this might work, would still prefer the non modal way, but this will have to do.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by having a transparent overlay that only appears when you're dragging the dialog. Here's some messy code that should give you the idea:

```
<div id="pod-overlay"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  var showOverlay =  function(event, ui) {
    $("#pod-overlay").attr("style", "z-index: 501; width: " + $(window).width() +
    "px; height: " + $(window).height() + "px; opacity:0.0;" +
    "position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;);")
  };
  var hideOverlay = function(event, ui) {
    $("#pod-overlay").attr("style", "");
  }; 
  $("#awesomewindow").dialog({
    dragStart: showOverlay,
    dragStop: hideOverlay,
    resizeStart: showOverlay,
    resizeStop: hideOverlay
  });
});
```